# React Native User Details Not Updating If name changes in CMS

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am working on a React Native Project after login we save the user details in redux state and clears it on logout but when logged in if a change made in username for user from CMS the updated details will not visible until I relogin to fetch the latest updated user details.

We are using a custom made CMS which we built on react and springboot.
Native app uses node as backend fetched the data from the same mysql database as CMS.

I am expecting a way to get new user details if any change made in cms .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.